What exactly is being done today to make Bitcoin "quantum-safe"?
A recent article on the potential threat of quantum computing to Bitcoin (and other cryptocurrencies) quotes an industry strategist:

...the crypto industry is working on "quantum-safe" crypto.

The article also says:

The National Institute of Standards and Technology (NIST) has released several quantum-safe algorithms that are resistant to attacks by future quantum computers, ..., and NIST has a timeline for governments and industry to deploy these algorithms to ensure the safety of the nation’s and businesses secrets.

I have not been able to find what is being done to make Bitcoin, in particular, quantum-safe.  Can someone point me to what is being done in this regard?

What do you mean by "in charge of"? Are you asking who is in charge

@RedGrittyBrick: I reworded my question in vaguer terms.  I hope you find this rewording more acceptable.

While there seems to be progress on quantum computing especially lately, from what I understand, quantum capabilities are still magnitudes away from being relevant to Bitcoin security. There recently were some post-quantum signature schemes published by NIST that garnered some interest in the Bitcoin community. It might be years or decades until quantum computing becomes actually relevant.
There is nobody in particular in charge of anything. However, there are some people working on a Bitcoin Improvement Proposal which aims to introduce a quantum-resistant output type: BIP-360: Pay to Quantum Resistant Hash. I’m sure as quantum computing improves, so will the interest in working on post-quantum security.

Thank you.  Something does not add up, somehow.  Maybe this is the Achilles heel of decentralization: no one is in charge of averting the potential sudden loss of billions of dollars' worth of value.  Or maybe I am greatly overestimating the risks.

@kjo: You mean, unlike assets with centralised responsibility for security such as the Venezuelan Bolivar, Enron and Lehrman brothers? :-)

@RedGrittyBrick: ever heard of "necessary but not sufficient"?
